# How can I login to a Novell Groupwise user account in C#?

Tags: c#, novell, groupwise

How can I use the login method to login to a user account in Novell Groupwise in C#?

Comment: what is it a winform app or AsP.net... please explain..

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16923344/214919

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally once the groupwise client was installed on a windows workstation the groupwise API (As bad as it is) would be available for use. A newer SOAP based api has superseded that for most tasks.